# PHP won't load WSDL, but browser displays XML fine?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am trying to access a Windows Service via SoapClient. When I type the ip:port in my browser, it loads the WSDL fine:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="RmJobService" targetNamespace="http://www.rimage.com/RmJobService">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.rimage.com/RmJobService/Imports">
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://ip:port/RmJobService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://www.rimage.com/RmJobService"/>
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://ip:port/RmJobService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://ip:port/RmJobService.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Rimage.Web.Service"/>
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://ip:port/RmJobService.svc?xsd=xsd3" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    ...etc...
```

But when I try to establish a SoapClient:

```
try 
{
    $sclient = new SoapClient('http://ip:port/RmJobService.svc?wsdl', array(
        "trace" => 1, "soap_version" => SOAP_1_1));
}
catch (SoapFault $ex)
{
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}
```

I get this error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://ip:port/RmJobService.svc?wsdl' : Start tag expected, '<' not found
```

Even trying to use `file_get_contents` or cURL returns null. Any ideas what is going on here?

Dave

Comment: Is there any white spaces at the line 1?

Comment: Sounds like that ip address is not accessible from your server. Is it some type of localhost by any chance, like 127.0.0.1 or something like that?

Comment: We've set up a static IP.. I can access the contents of port 80 via cURL no problem.

Comment: You are able to curl the domain on port 80, but not on the port your wsdl resides on?

Comment: @ben correct... not sure what's going on.

Comment: after you curl, call curl_error() and curl_errno() on the handler. If there is no error, try curl_getinfo().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a server firewall issue. Check with the host to make sure it could connect to the source and once they opened the port, everything worked fine. Dumb.